# Can multiple base64 documents be stored in a single file?

Tags: base64

If files are converted to base64 format can they be put in a single file?

Is there a way they can be prefixed and postfixed in the file to allow them to be extracted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, of course you can.  They are just strings (and a subset at that).  Choose any delimiter that is not part of your Base64 encoding (for example, "$"), and concatenate to your heart's content.

Comment: did you see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21569276/multiple-base64-files-in-one ?