# fonts base64 encoded in css but still multiple requests?

Tags: css, base64, stylesheet, font-face

I'm wondering if this is the right behavior.

As I have the fonts in the stylesheet base64 encoded
I'm still seeing multiple requests with 0 bytes.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: local('Open Sans'), local('OpenSans'), url('data:application/x-font-woff;base64,ENCODED_STRING') format('woff');
}
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: might be this link helpful for you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21569276/multiple-base64-files-in-one

Comment: but this is not related to my question - I have asked why there are these empty requests when I have already included the four base64 encoded fonts in the CSS. The point is if it is normal to have these empty requests or not.